# scanf taking int but continues execution only after entering another char/int and pressing enter

Tags: c, scanf

In my code (in c) `scanf()` takes one integer value but when I type an integer and press enter then nothing happens (the execution do not continue as it should). I need to press on a key and only then the program continue with the number I did press first.

example:
code:

```
int num=0;
printf("Enter a number and see if he belong to one of the groups:");
scanf("%d\n\n",&num);
```

Output:

```
Enter a number and see if he belong to one of the groups:5(enter) 

f(enter)
```

and only then the code continues....

Comment: Try `scanf("%d",&num);`, scanf will automatically skip whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you are telling `scanf` to read two newline characters, not one:

```
scanf("%d\n\n", &num);
```

This should give the right behaviour instead:

```
scanf("%d\n", &num);
```

Answer (score 1):

If accepted solution of

```
scanf("%d\n", &num);
```

works differently than your posted code, you have a non-compliant compiler.  The whitespace after the `"%d"`, if `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `" "` or others as well as the number of them should make no difference.  They all consume 0 or more following whitespace(s).  `scanf("%d\n", &num)` does not return until a non-whitespace (or EOF) is entered.

As @pepo suggests, use

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

or better yet, use `fgets()/sscanf()`.